# Append datatypes in array of dictionary (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, data-structures, type-conversion

i have array1 form of array and I want to convert it in order to be like array2

```
const array1 = [
  {name:'sds',long:'23',lat:'22'}, 
  {name:'sdsd',long:'33',lat:'55'}, 
  {name:'sds',long:'44',lat:'66'}
];

const array2 = [
  {name:'sds',long:23,lat:22}, 
  {name:'sdsd',long:33,lat:55}, 
  {name:'sds',long:44,lat:66}
];
```

basically, I want to change the datatype of longitude and latitude**(java script** ) please If u know do tell me

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/1048572

Comment: yes i have to use it by using foreach loop but it didn't work

Comment: foreach is a good start, what didn't work though? Can you show what you did?

Comment: oky so i have take an empty array and tried to append the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map over the array and convert `string` to `Number`, by appending `+` to `String` type will make `String` type to `Number` type.

```
array1.map(({ name, long, lat }) => ({ name, long: +long, lat: +lat }));
```

```js
const array1 = [
  { name: "sds", long: "23", lat: "22" },
  { name: "sdsd", long: "33", lat: "55" },
  { name: "sds", long: "44", lat: "66" },
];

const result = array1.map(({ name, long, lat }) => ({ name, long: +long, lat: +lat }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this answer the best.  Wht does `+long` do actually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

A crude and brute force way is:

```js
const array1 = [
  {name:'sds',long:'23',lat:'22'}, 
  {name:'sdsd',long:'33',lat:'55'}, 
  {name:'sds',long:'44',lat:'66'}
];


const x  = array1.map(y => {
    // console.log(y);
    y.long = parseInt(y.long);
    y.lat = parseInt(y.lat);
    return y; 
});

console.log(x);
```

Output will be as expected.  It basically maps each item and does the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, you can try this. Hope this will help you. Thanks.

```js
const array1 = [
  {name:'sds',long:'23',lat:'22'}, 
  {name:'sdsd',long:'33',lat:'55'}, 
  {name:'sds',long:'44',lat:'66'}
];

const array2 = array1.map(item => ({
  name: item.name,
  long: parseInt(item.long),
  lat: parseInt(item.lat),
}));

console.log(array2)
```